# Calculate precipitation from WRF model output

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, atmosphere-modelling, wrf

From WRF output file,

I find 3 variables related to the precipitation (unit: mm)

**1. Precipitation**

- variable name: pr
- unit:$kg/(m^{2}s^1)$
- variable: RAINC+RAINNC
- comments: $dt(RAINC+RAINNC)/DT$

**2. Max hourly precipitation rate**

- variable name: prhmax
- unit:$kg/(m^{2}s^1)$
- variable: RAINC, RAINNC or RAINMAX1Hclwrf
- comments: $MAX(dtsum()/DT)$

**3. Convective precipitation**

- variable name: prc
- unit:$kg/(m^{2}s^1)$
- variable: RAINC
- comments: $d_t(RAINC)/DT $

My task:

> Summarize the amount of days which precipitation > 0.254 mm

What variable should I use for further analysis?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use (1) Precipitation, as it is the sum of convective and non-convective precipitation, integrate it over one day, voilà.

converting [$kg/(m^2 s)$] (precip):
$$ precip [kg/(m^2 s)] \cdot dt [s] \cdot \frac{1}{ \rho_w [kg/(m^3)]} \cdot 1000 [mm/m] = total\_precip [mm]$$

where $\rho_w$ is the density of water.

Practically the last two factors cancel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have known the meaning of sum RAINS & RAINNS. But you answer let me know why the units change to $mm$. That's very helpful!